# How to Create a NSSortDescriptor that Sorts by Multiple Keys with One Selector

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

My data model is as such:

```
User (Entity)
- valueOne (NSNumber Attribute)
- valueTwo (NSNumber Attribute)
```

I am using an `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch `User` entities from Core Data to display in my `UITableView`. I am having trouble sorting the results of the fetch request. I need to sort by `valueOne (divided by) valueTwo`. I have tried passing both `@"self"` and `nil` for the Key value of `sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:selector:` to obtain the `User` object. I would then sort by the `User.valueOne / User.valueTwo` values in my custom selector, but neither `@"self"` or `nil` seem to work, as I get errors for both. The documentation doesn't seem to contain anything about how to pass the parent object for the key to sort by.

How would I go about creating an `NSSortDescriptor` which sorts by `valueOne / valueTwo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. The sort descriptor for a Core Data fetch request can only sort
according to (persistent) attributes of the entities. Transient attributes or custom
(Objective-C based) comparator methods cannot be used.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to respond. Since my proposed method is not possible, maybe you could point me in the right direction as to how I could produce this effect alternatively?

Comment: @AdamK: As far as I know, the only solution is to store valueOne/valueTwo as another persistent attribute in the entity. - Alternatively, you can fetch all objects and sort them in memory with a custom sort method. But then you lose all the advantages of a fetched results controller.